# PHP 5.3.3 puzzle, what it prints and why

Tags: php, puzzle, ternary-operator

Why it doesn't print what is suppose to print?

```
<?php 
$place = 1; 
echo $place === 1 ? 'a' : $place === 2 ? 'b' : 'c'; 
?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything printed :?

Comment: from the manual "It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:" http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Karthik: because `$place !== 1`?? I what case would `$place` actually be `=== 1` then, if not in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The manual is your friend](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Quote:

```
<?php
// on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');

// however, the actual output of the above is 't'
// this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

// the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

// here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
// in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
// second ternary expression.
```

You are basically doing:

```
echo ($place === 1 ? 'a' : $place === 2) ? 'b' : 'c';
// which is
echo 'a' ? 'b' : 'c';
// which is
echo 'b';
```

Comment: I'm confused with this line <?php echo 'a' ? 'b' : 'c'; ?>
i mean what he checked is a is empty ?? or something else ??

Comment: @MBTheDeveloper PHP is loosely typed and does lot's of type juggling. In PHP `'a' == true` (because `'a'` is a non-empty, non-zero string)

Comment: thanks i just confused with his 2nd condition but now understand why its true.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo ($place === 1 ? 'a' : $place === 2) ? 'b' : 'c';
echo ('a') ? 'b' : 'c';
echo (true) ? 'b' : 'c';
echo 'b';
```

Thats why.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator evaluates from left to right, so you should write

```
echo ($place === 1 ? 'a' : $place === 2)  ? 'b' : 'c';
echo (true         ? 'a' : $place === 2)  ? 'b' : 'c';
echo 'a'                                  ? 'b' : 'c';
echo true                                 ? 'b' : 'c'; // outputs b
```

to clarify. This behavior is [well-documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 1):

What do you think it is supposed to print and why, and what is being printed?

Also, from the PHP manual on ternary expressions:

> Note:
>
> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:

```
<?php

  // on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
  echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');

  // however, the actual output of the above is 't'
  // this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

  // the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
  echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

  // here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
  // in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
  // second ternary expression.

?>
```